# CodedUI Test: How to run from Web Portal (MS Test Manager's replacement)

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Using the Test hub in the Web Portal why is the "Associated Automation" tab completely empty, greyed out and prevented from being used?

What do I need to do to enable all this and run a coded ui test? I have hand coded, Coded UI tests that are build and in dlls but need to run the tests in those dlls in my test suite.

For background, I can run the tests in the dlls using a batch file and have done so successfully but struggling to get started running them from my test plan! My Microsoft "Test Manager" has the same problem, all greyed out but as Test Manager is being deprecated I am less concerned about that.

[image]

**EDIT**:

Another way of viewing this problem is to ask why does the Automation Status not show the option "Automated"? See picture below ...

[image]

Comment: With Coded UI and MTM, linking the automated test must be done from Visual Studio. MTM would show that the test is automated and would run it, but MTM does not provide any way of connecting (or making or linking) the Coded UI test to a test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible per [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case#add-test).

In the visual studio development environment, try right clicking on a test in test explorer, clicking something such as "Associate to Test Case", then entering in the test case number and see if that works.  I believe it is greyed out because there is no valid input options through the web right now.

Comment: Sorry I don't have Visual Studio on this domain. Is there a way to do it in Microsoft Test Manager or the web portal under the "Test" tab?

Comment: I do not believe so (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case#add-test).  The only way in which I have seen documentation to associate them is through visual studio, and that is also the only way I have done it.